# simplifying summations inspired by binomial coefficient and binomial distribution

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, algebra-precalculus

Is it possible  to simplify the following summations?

\begin{align}
C&=\sum_{k=0}^N k\rho^k{N \choose k}   
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
P&= \sum_{k=0}^N k\rho^k P(N,k)= \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^N k\rho^k{N \choose k}   k!
\end{align}

Here, $C$ and $P$ stand for combination and permutation.  Given that it easy to simplify the following expression, I was wondering if the corresponding expressions above are also amenable to simplification.

\begin{align}
E&=\sum_{k=0}^N \rho^k{N \choose k}    \\
&= (1+\rho)^N
\end{align}

P.S.: if the expressions are not amenable to exact simplification, would there be a way to approximate them in closed form?

Comment: $E=(1+\rho)^N$, not $\rho^N$.

Comment: $$k{N\choose k}=N{N-1\choose k-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

For $C$, absorb the $k$ via $k\binom{N}{k}=N\binom{N-1}{k-1}$, and then apply the binomial theorem to obtain $C=N \rho(1+\rho)^{N-1}$.